# How to get data to fill alternative cells when data is present in a zigzag pattern

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kwGbFd88cgifQRK_ZqsahQt1aDLzMTnmxHKs7mML5jA/edit?usp=sharing

How to get data entered in one cell to fill another cell in a different location with same values simultaneously when it is above or below certain  values but when data is already present there to default to second or third alternative location that will be located either directly to the right or to the right and below present in a zigzag pattern.

the link has a detailed description of the question

[image: 0]

Comment: updated link sorry , i have tried index and match but could not  get to work but i am not very familiar with either.

Comment: That works for filling in values out of the columns that is already there but i was hoping for something that would take a value i entered and place it in the next available slot without rearranging the existing data that was already there kind of like once it has been simultaneously entered it is locked in there that way if a value in between a previous set of values comes up that fits the criteria it wont cause a reordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: 0]

### E141:

```
=QUERY({$C$5:$C$110; $J$5:$J$110; $Q$5:$Q$110}, 
 "where Col1 is not null order by Col1 limit 1", 0)
```

### F141:

```
=QUERY({$C$5:$C$110; $J$5:$J$110; $Q$5:$Q$110}, 
 "where Col1 is not null order by Col1 limit 1 offset 1", 0)
```

### F140:

```
=QUERY({$C$5:$C$110; $J$5:$J$110; $Q$5:$Q$110}, 
 "where Col1 is not null order by Col1 limit 1 offset 2", 0)
```

### E139:

```
=QUERY({$C$5:$C$110; $J$5:$J$110; $Q$5:$Q$110}, 
 "where Col1 is not null order by Col1 limit 1 offset 3", 0)
```

### F139:

```
=QUERY({$C$5:$C$110; $J$5:$J$110; $Q$5:$Q$110}, 
 "where Col1 is not null order by Col1 limit 1 offset 4", 0)
```

etc.

---

or like:

[image: 0]

Comment: D0 I wrap that in an IF statement to set critera <=-700

Comment: you can narrow it down like this: `=IFERROR(QUERY({$C$5:$C$110; $J$5:$J$110; $Q$5:$Q$110}, 
 "where Col1 is not null and Col1 <=-800 order by Col1 limit 1 offset 8", 0))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8WcA.png

Comment: @XCATHADOR https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers